# Android access webservice with SOAP

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I am making currency converter with real time data,using ksoap to access webservice. However  the response which is come from webservice is org.ksoap2.SoapFault.But this answers is not throwing as a exception. This answer comes to my text area what is wrong in my code?

Here is source code :

```
    package com.example.deneme;

    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        TextView input;
        TextView output;
        Button convert;

        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";

        private static String URL = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"; 
        private static final String METHOD_NAME = "ConversionRate";
        private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate";

     // Yararlanacağımız web servisin yerini belirtiyoruz.
        /*
        final static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        // Web servis üzerinde hangi metodu kullanacağımızı ayarlıyoruz.
        final static String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
        // SOAP_ACTION : NAMESPACE ve METHOD_NAME birleşiminden oluşuyor.
        final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
        // Son olarak Web servise ait URL tanımlamasını burada yapıyoruz.
        final static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
        */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         convert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.convertt);
         convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

                /*
                  PropertyInfo propInfo=new PropertyInfo();
                  propInfo.name="FromCurrency";
                  propInfo.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                  propInfo.setValue("GBP");


                  PropertyInfo propInfo2 = new PropertyInfo();
                  propInfo2.name="ToCurrency";
                  propInfo2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                  propInfo2.setValue("EUR");
            */
                //  request.addProperty(propInfo);
                  //request.addProperty(propInfo2);
                request.addProperty("FromCurrency","GBP");
                request.addProperty("ToCurrency","AFA");

                  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

                  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                  envelope.dotNet=true;

                  AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

                  try {
                      httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                   System.out.println("2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                   SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;


                   System.out.println("1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");


                  input.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());



                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      input.setText(e.getMessage());

                  }
            }
        });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtUoD.png
```

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: there is no exception this is the response from server in this picture

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QtUoD.png

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a code segment like this,

```
AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
try {
   httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
   System.out.println("2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
   SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
   System.out.println("1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
   input.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
  input.setText(e.getMessage());
}
```

Please replace the above part with this,

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
Object result = envelope.getResponse();
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

This will work. Also Please read this blog. It has a working code for you. http://www.insightforfuture.blogspot.com/2012/02/accessing-apache-axis2-web-service_24.html